# finding parent in binary search tree

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

Here is the code to find parent in Binary search tree. I am not able to understand how is it working, as we are never assigning any value to parent other than null. I an new to recursion.

```
public Node findParent(Type data) 
{
    return findParent(data, root, null);
}

public Node findParent(Type x, Node node, Node parent) 
{
    if (node == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (!(node.data == x)) {
        parent = findParent(x, node.left, node);
        if (parent == null) {
            parent = findParent(x, node.right, node);
        }
    }
    return parent;
}
```

Comment: I must admit, in addition to the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27034602/733637) by @Eran, that the code does not seem to make any use of the tree being a BST — it seeks the value given both in a left and in a right subtree of the current node, not testing whether the value given in the `x` parameter is less than or greater than the `x` member of the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a non null value to parent in the recursive calls :

```
parent = findParent(x, node.left, node);
                                  ----
parent = findParent(x, node.right, node);
                                   ----
```

`parent` is null only in the initial call (since the root of the tree has no parent).

Each call to `findParent` gets a value (`x`), a Node (`node`) and the parent Node of that Node (`parent`). If that value is found in the Node, parent is returned, otherwise, you search for that value in the left sub-tree, and if it's still not found, you search for it in the right sub-tree.

Comment: I have another stupid Qs to add to it (being new to Java)... Why there are two methods here .. one public and other private. Why can't be simply make private method public and get rid of current public method ?

Comment: @Andy897 Both methods are public, but I'm assuming the second one is supposed to be private. Making it private hides the implementation of `findParent(Type data)` from the outside world. If you do as you suggest, the caller of the now private method would have to call `findParent(data, root, null)` instead of the simpler call to `findParent(data)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here I put some comments in it. Tell me if it not seems clear. (Recursion is hard to explain)

```
// The method
public Node findParent(Type x, Node node, Node parent)
{
    // if this node is null, return null, cause this 
    // is not the path you are looking for
    if (node == null) {
        return null;
        // if this is not the node we are looking for,
    } else if (!(node.data == x)) {
        // We look in the left node.
        parent = findParent(x, node.left, node);
        // If its not found parent will be null
        if (parent == null) {
            // So we go look to the right
            parent = findParent(x, node.right, node);
        }
    }
    // Eventually we can return the parent.
    // If this was the node we were looking for,
    // We can return parent without changing it.
    // If it was not, this algorithm searched in its subtrees
    // If its not there than parent is null.
    return parent;
}
```